# Handling relative paths in a presented webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a custom UIViewController with a UIWebViewDelegate. I've presented a webpage based on a url.

I'm having issues with some of the links on this page as they are relative paths. Tapping on those links do nothing but I'd like to get the links opened in safari or within the view controller.

I've experimented with getting the contents of the URL `NSString(contentsOf: url, encoding: someInt)` and trying to add the baseUrl back but this is very clunky and not ideal.

Are there other ways I can approach this?

Comment: Why don't you open the webpage in Safari in the first place?

Comment: @Sweeper it's not my call...the initial webpage must be within the app, but the other links within that page is free to be opened in safari